# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'size' in Node2Vec

Tags: python-3.x, graph, gensim, word2vec

I am embedding a graph with Node2Vec library but I am getting this as error :
**TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'size'** to the following code block -

```
model = node2vec.fit(window=10, min_count=1, batch_words=4)
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: You would need to paste the entire error message in your answer, including the traceback of involved lines-of-code/files, to give answerers the best chance of knowing what's gone wrong. Is it still a problem, or, per your comment on a deleted answer, is it no longer a problem because "I restarted the runtime and issue was solved miraculuously"?

Answer (score 2):

You have to downgrade gensim from (in my case) `4.1.2` to `3.8.3`.
I was using node2vec `0.4.3`
This issue was supposed to be fixed since 4.2 but for some reason I still had it.
https://githubmemory.com/repo/eliorc/node2vec/issues/60

Comment: Sorry, I did not find the version with 4.2. I have used the same version with node2vec and gensim as yours. But the problem is still there.

Comment: So you did downgrade gensim to 3.8.3 ?

Comment: Steps to downgrade are :  pip uninstall gensim && pip  install gensim==3.8.3